# How many fans does a 2.26 GHz 15" 2009 MacBook Pro 5,5 have?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I have a 15" MacBook Pro 2.26 GHz purchased in late 2009, model "MacBookPro5,5".

The FanControl PrefPane reports

```
Right Fan: -1 RPM
```

Does this model only have one fan, or does it have two?

Answer (score 1):

Two fans, unless it's a trick question and you consider them blowers :-)

See http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2009+Right+Fan/1710/1

Comment: Hm. That link is for "2.66 GHz" and faster. I have 2.26 GHz. Does that make a difference? This page appears to only show 1 fan: http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+2.53+GHz+Mid+2009+Fan/1536/1